# Can the name of Writers.SE be changed to Writing.SE in the Help Center?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

The Help Center, specifically the page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), currently says:

> 2. Questions about creating literature yourself—you may want to try the [Writers Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Writers.SE has been renamed to Writing.SE last year. Here is the relevant meta announcement: [This site is now Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/23159)

Can the name in the Help Center be updated to reflect this change?

Comment: Done. (Characters.)